# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una función aleatoriamente en Bash?

Tags: funciones, bash, random

Tengo 3 functions en mi script bash:

```
function opcion1(){
echo "función uno"
}

function opcion2(){
echo "función dos"
}

function opcion3(){
echo "función tres"
}
```

Necesito saber cómo llamar a alguna de estas 3 funciones de manera random, de modo que la llamada pueda ser a alguna de estas tres funciones, pero de manera aleatoria.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Haz un array con funciones, y luego escoges una función aleatoriamente con `$RANDOM % 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar RANDOM para construir el nombre de la función a llamar, y después utilizar ese nombre para ejecutar la función:

```
function opcion1(){
   echo "función uno"
}

function opcion2(){
   echo "función dos"
}

function opcion3(){
   echo "función tres"
}

NUM=$(echo "($RANDOM % 3) + 1" | bc)
FUNC="opcion$NUM"

$FUNC
```

Comment: Cumple con lo que se pide, pero tiene mucha paja como: 1. Se puede prescindir de `bc`, 2. Se puede prescindir de `echo`, 3. Se puede prescindir de asignar a la variable `FUNC`

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta aceptada cumple con lo que se pide, pero tiene cosas extra que resuelvo de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

opcion1(){
   echo "función uno"
}

opcion2(){
   echo "función dos"
}

opcion3(){
   echo "función tres"
}

random_opt=$(( $RANDOM % 3 + 1 ))
#              |
#              |_____ Hacemos una expansión aritmética y lo asignamos 
#                     a una variable.
#                     De esta manera evitamos hacer cálculos utilizando
#                     programas extra

opcion${random_opt}
```

Con este script, puede hacer lo siguiente para ejecutarlo:

```
$ while :
do
./f_aleatorio.sh
sleep 1
done
función dos
función tres
función uno
función uno
...
```